# Listing azure webapp name of a group by powershell

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-powershell, azure-cli, azure-cloud-shell

Is there any way to list all webapp service of a certain group by azure cli or azure powershell script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do with

PowerShell [Get-AzWebApp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.websites/get-azwebapp?view=azps-6.2.1)

```
Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName "yourRGName"
```

Comment: It's showing the following error on powershell....
`Get-AzWebApp : The term 'Get-AzWebApp' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName "mygroup"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-AzWebApp:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException`

Comment: Did you read it well? it's a Azure CLI command not powershell

Comment: Get-AzWebApp *is* Azure PowerShell cmdlet.

Comment: Yeah right, i got confused between az and AzWebApp

Comment: @Akashpaul you need to install the necessary modules to work with